# Knockout Issue with $parent in nested objects

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am having problems with accessing the parent object within a view model when the parent object is not at root level.

For example, the following works (http://jsfiddle.net/rampmr/4r7zep25/)

```
  <div>
    <!-- ko foreach: items -->

        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.chosenItems" />
        <span data-bind="text:$data"></span> <br>

    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko foreach: chosenItems -->
            Checked values are <span data-bind="text:$data"></span> <br>
    <!-- /ko -->
    </div>

    <script>

        $(function(){       

            function viewModel() {
                    var self = this;
                    self.items = ko.observableArray();
                    self.chosenItems= ko.observableArray()
                    self.items.push('Choice 1','Choice 2' );
                    self.chosenItems().push('Choice 1');
                        console.log(self);
                }
        var vm = new viewModel();
            ko.applyBindings(vm);

       });


    </script>
```

However when I have an object inside the View Model and the object has an array, I am unable to reach the object using $parent when iterating the array (http://jsfiddle.net/rampmr/4nsjn948/4/)

```
<DIV>

<!-- ko foreach: customValues.avblFruits -->
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $parent.Fruits" />
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
<!-- /ko -->

</DIV>

<br>

<DIV>

<!-- ko foreach: customValues.Fruits -->    
    Selected Values are <span data-bind="text: $data"></span> <br>
<!-- /ko -->

</DIV>

<script>

    $(function(){       

        var selectedValues = {"Fruits" : ['Apple']};

        var availableValues = {"avblFruits" : ['Apple', 'Orange']};

        function CustomValues(data){
                var self = this;
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
                ko.mapping.fromJS(availableValues, {}, self);
                console.log(self);
        }

        var mapping = {
            create: function (options) {
                return new CustomValues(options.data);
            }
        };

        function viewModel() {
                var self = this;
                self.customValues = ko.mapping.fromJS(selectedValues, mapping );                            
                console.log(self);

            }
    var vm = new viewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    }); 


</script>
```

When I change

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $parent.Fruits" />
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.customValues.Fruits" />
```

Any ideas why it is not working with $parent ?

Comment: it will work try like this http://jsfiddle.net/4nsjn948/5/ cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you are trying to refer `parent` which doesn't exist as per your view structure . Try using `with` binding which suits the case and you can use `$parent` or `$root` respectively .

**view:**

```
<div data-bind="with:customValues"> //level 1 
<!-- ko foreach:avblFruits --> // level 2 i.e level 1 is parent of level 2
 <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $parent.Fruits" /> 
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

working sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/4nsjn948/6/)**

Comment: Wonderful - thanks. Makes sense when I think about it. Somehow I was under the impression that within the forEach of an array variable of an object , I am under the parent object's context and not at the root.